# How/Where do I store my .db file on android

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I already have my .db file, but I don't know where to store it to make the connection trough the path.

I'm  using xamarin within visual studio 2017 and for the test my personal phone.

Comment: include it as an asset in your project.  When you first run, you will need to copy it from assets to a writable path and then access it from there

Comment: Should the writable path be on my phone? If that's it, I'm thinking using 'storage/emulated/0/'

Comment: Yes.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/

Comment: And how do I copy it? I don't see the 'Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal' folder when I connect the phone to the pc

Comment: Your **APP** need to do this when it starts up the first time.

Comment: It doesn't, I already copied db to assets folder and tried to do the connection

Comment: When your app starts the FIRST time, it needs to programmatically copy the file from assets to a writable folder.  You then make the db connection to the file in the writable folder.

Comment: @DragutinovicDr If you want to use this sqlite database in one project, you can run your project firstly, then copy this dabatase in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app/files/, for an application with the package name com.companyname.app, then you will get connection by `Context context = Android.App.Application.Context; var filePath = context.GetExternalFilesDir("");  return filePath.Path;` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=macos

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use Android studio. I'm a new student too, and to create a DB you should use SQLite. When you don't pick a path where you want to create you're database.db, the database.db will be created inside your application folder: from device: file explorer (Android studio [file explorer option]:sdcard/Android/data/(yourappURI,ex:com.android.example.myapplication))
From your computer: yourdevice/Android/data/com.android.example.myapplication

(I'm new here, if I'm wrong please correct me)

Comment: Telling someone to use a completely different platform just to avoid one small problem they are facing is not in any way helpful.